Firebase fetching collection incorrectly returns empty result
I am currently building an app using firebase as the database. I am trying to fetch the categories of my user, however, even though I can see in my firebase console that the user actually has 3 categories (I added them by default upon registration).
I tried to debug but could not figure out why it happens. Furthermore, I looked for similar problems and moved my code when I call the function into the .onAppear method. None of these attempts worked...
Here is my firebase console:

Code for fetching categories in my Firebase Manager class:
func fetchCategories(forUserId userId: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Category], Error>) -> Void) {
        
        let categoriesRef = db.collection("users").document(userId).collection("categories")
        print("user id: \(userId)")
        categoriesRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
                return
            }

            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
                completion(.failure(FirestoreErrorCode.notFound as! Error))
     
                return
            }

            let categories = documents.compactMap { document -> Category? in
                do {
                    return try document.data(as: Category.self)
                } catch {
                    print("Error decoding category: \(error)")
                    return nil
                }
            }

            completion(.success(categories))
        }
    }

Calling the function:
.onAppear {
                FirebaseManager().fetchCategories(forUserId: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "") { result in
                    do {
                        let categories = try result.get()
                        print("fetched categories")
                        print(categories.isEmpty ? categories : categories[0])
                        if categories.isEmpty == false {
                            firstCategory = categories[0]
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("Error fetching categories: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                    
                }
            }

If I should provide anything else, please just say!
UPDATE!
As the comments suggested, I implemented a categories array in my firebaseManager class:
private var db = Firestore.firestore()

@Published var categories: [Category] = []

init() {
    if let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        fetchCategories(userID: userID)
    }
}

I also altered my fetch Categories function:
func fetchCategories(userID: String) {
    let docRef = db.collection("categories").document(userID)
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error", error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            return
        }
        
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let data = document.data()
            if let data = data {
                print("data", data)
                self.categories = data["categories"] as? [Category] ?? []
                print(self.categories)
            }
        }
        
    }
}

Furthermore, I am now accessing my categories array via an @EnvironmentObject of my FirebaseManager class:
@EnvironmentObject var firebaseManager: FirebaseManager

var categories: [Category] {
    var categories = firebaseManager.categories
    print(categories)
    return categories
}

Moreover, I added an @StateObject to my @main App declaration and added it to the first loaded View in WindowGroup:
WindowGroup {
        ZStack {
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                let _ = print("content view triggered when loading app")
                ContentView()
                    .environmentObject(firebaseManager)
                    .environmentObject(userData)
            } else {
                let _ = print("welcome view triggered when loading app")
                WelcomeScreen()
                    .environment(firebaseManager)
                    .environmentObject(userData)  
            }
        }
    }

That, how far I've come. Unfortunately, it still does not work...
UPDATE 2
I have managed to get data from Firebase. However, now I have the problem, that I cannot decode the data to my Category type.
func fetchCategories(userID: String) {
    let docRef = db.collection("users").document(userID)
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error", error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            return
        }
        
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let data = document.data()
            if let data = data {
                print("data", data)
                //self.categories = data["categories"] as? [Category] ?? []
                self.categories.append(contentsOf: data["categories"] as? [Category] ?? [Category(title: "Category", emoji: "", items: [
                    Item(title: "ToDo Nr.1", emoji: "", priority: .high)
                    ])])
            }
        } else {
            print("no document exists")
        }
        
    }
}

I did implement the codable protocol in my Category type. However, I am not sure how to apply that to data coming from firebase.
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
    try container.encode(title, forKey: .title)
    try container.encode(emoji, forKey: .emoji)
    try container.encode(items, forKey: .items)
}

required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    id = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id)
    title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
    emoji = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .emoji)
    items = try container.decode([Item].self, forKey: .items)
}


        func fetchCategories(forUserId userId: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Category], Error>) -> Void) {
    let userRef = db.collection("users").document(userId)
    print("user id: \(userId)")
    
    userRef.getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
            return
        }
        guard let document = snapshot, document.exists else {
            completion(.failure(FirestoreErrorCode.notFound as! Error))
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let data = document.data()
            if let categoriesArray = data?["categories"] as? [[String: Any]
            {
                let categories = try categoriesArray.compactMap { 
                   dict -> Category? in  
                    return try Category(from: dict)
                 }
                completion(.success(categories))
            } else {
                completion(.success([])) // Return an empty array if no categories are found
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error decoding category: \(error)")
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}


    .onAppear {
    FirebaseManager().fetchCategories(forUserId: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "") { result in
        do {
            let categories = try result.get()
            print("fetched categories")
            print(categories.isEmpty ? categories : categories[0])
            if categories.isEmpty == false {
                firstCategory = categories[0]
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching categories: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

**Try it and let me know if you are encountering any error post the error here also
**

Code only answers are discouraged, please add some explanation to your solution

This error occurs: Argument type '[String : Any]' does not conform to expected type 'Decoder' in line: "return try Category(from: dict)"

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
